# Why does co-partitioning of two Kstreams in kafka require same number of partitions for both the streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I wanted to know why does co-partitioning of two Kstreams in kafka require same number of partitions for both the streams as is given in the documentation in below URL:
[enter link description here](http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#joining)

Comment: this OP's link is broken I believe this new link helps  <Partition Data to Enable Joins> https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/partition-data.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As the name "co-partition" indicates, you want to put data from different topics but same key to the same Kafka Streams application instance. If you don't have the same number of partitions, it's not possible to get this behavior.

Assume you have topic A with 2 partitions and topic B with 3 partitions. Thus, it can happen that one record with key X is hashed to partitions A-0 and B-1 (ie, not same partition number). However, for a different key Y it might be hashed to A-0 but B-2.

Only if the number of partitions is the same for both topics, records with same key end up in the same partitions (of different topics of course), and this allows to process A-0/B-0 and A-1/B-1 etc together.

Comment: Something seem missing in your explanation that i would like to further understand. How is it possible, that the assignment of partition will be the same in two different consumer group ? Let say that the number of partition is the same, and the partitioning strategy is the same. If it is 2 different consumer group, how come consumer in both consumer group get assigned to the same partition. That part is quite fuzy to me.

Comment: I have opened a new question on that, with a link to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57220589/how-do-co-partitioning-ensure-that-partition-from-2-different-topics-end-up-assi

Comment: This question is not about two consumer groups, but one consumer group.